# How to pass query string parameter in angularJS and how to receive it on node server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am making an api call through my service, as follows:

```
$http.get('/api/subCategories/'+parent).success(function(response){
        $scope.subCategories = response;
});
```

The variable `parent` is what I want to use as a query string.
I suspect this is not the correct way of passing the query string. It should be something like `'/api/categories?parent='+parent`. I am not sure though.

Then, how do I receive this query string in app.js (i.e. on the server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that your initial example is not a query string. A [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is always prefixed with `?`, as in your second example. As for receiving its value on the server, I'm not really sure if you just want to know how to parse it, or if you want to know how to set up the whole server. If you just want to parse a query string in Node, you can use the built-in [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) and [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) modules like so:

```
const url = require('url');
const querystring = require('querystring');

let mockUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/categories?parent=babar';

let query = url.parse(mockUrl).query; // => 'parent=babar'
let data = querystring.parse(query); // => { parent: 'babar' }

console.log(data.parent); // => 'babar'
```

If you want to know how to set up a minimal server that will handle a request with a query string, I would suggest using [express](http://expressjs.com/) rather than Node's built-in features. In combination with [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), you won't even have to worry about the parsing bit:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

// Configure server to parse JSON for us
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Handle request to our route
app.get('/api/categories', (req, res) => {
  // Do something with the value of the query property:
  console.log(req.query.parent);
});

// Start the server at http://localhost:8080
app.listen(8080);
```

For more detail at a quite introductory level, you might find this [blog post](http://junerockwell.com/difference-parameters-query-strings-express-js/) useful: